# Unable to install Mechanize using Cygwin in Windows ( ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.)

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have been unsuccessful to install Mechanize 
My current ruby version 2.0.0

This is what the error I get

```
$ gem install mechanize
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mechanize:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lstdc++... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-stdc++lib
        --without-stdc++lib
/usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:in `try_link0'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `try_link'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:720:in `try_func'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:950:in `block in have_library'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:895:in `block in checking_for'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block in postpone'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `postpone'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:894:in `checking_for'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:945:in `have_library'
        from extconf.rb:2:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/Dennis/.gem/ruby/gems/unf_ext-0.0.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/Dennis/.gem/ruby/gems/unf_ext-0.0.6/ext/unf_ext/gem_make.out
```

I have tried this [solution](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/problem-installing-mechanize-gem.121169/) but is not working for me. I still receiving this similiar error.

I also have nokogiri installed. I wonder what is the problem here...

Comment: I'm running this in Cygwin. Sorry for any unclear.

Answer (score 1):

To build the native extensions, you need the development kit installed.

Go to the [Ruby Installer download page](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/), download the **DEVELOPMENT KIT** according to your Ruby and system version, install the kit to an appropriate directory and then reinstall the gem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for unclear topic, my Ruby is run under cygwin. I'm not sure where is the development kit suppose to be located.

Comment: @Dennis, It doesn't matter where you put devkit, but you need follow the instructions or it won't work.